# Завтрак, обед, ужин

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а какое происхождение у этих слов? Более-менее можно объяснить только "завтрак" - трапеза на завтра (хотя тоже сомнительно). А вот что с обедом и ужином? В украинском языке ужин - это "вечеря", все понятно. А откуда взялось русское?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Завтрак — это др.-рус. заутрокъ, то есть утренняя еда, что верно с XI века.

Обед по времени не обозначен, но во время обеда думаем только о нем. Это общеславянское слово с корнем ЕД-, то есть "есть, еда, а также яд и мясоед" — родственные слова. ОБ - приставка, то есть обед — время еды.

С ужином всё напутали, в действительности это полдник в полдень, когда солнце находится на юге (слово "ужин" происходит от слова "юг"). В других славянских языках ужин называют "вечеря", в др.-рус. языке с XI века — это еда в полдень, но уже в XVII веке иностранные наблюдатели фиксируют современное значение слова: ужин — это supper.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что всё гораздо проще: обед — это трансформированное "апат", еда, кушанье (дренетюркское), сохранилось в совр. чувашском языке.

Ужин — опять же оттуда: "ошан" (в чув.): подогретое, разогретое, т.е. еда, оставшаяся после обеда, и вновь разогретая.

Comment: А зачем нам, русским заимствовать у татар слово, в котором чисто русский корень "ед"?)))

Comment: Что за прелесть, этот подогретый трансчувашский язык!